# React Native UI Kitten How to override default colour for components like Spinners and Progress Bars

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm trying to change the colour of a spinner and a progress bar on one screen only, so don't want to mess around with the default EVA colourscheme.

I can pass in backgroundColor to the style but that doesn't change the colour of the actual bar or spinner. Is there an easy way to override the default?

```
<ProgressBar
     size="giant"
     progress={progress_value}
     style={{
     backgroundColor: "pink"
           }}
/>
```